# Combo lost selected value

Tags: java, spring, extjs, model-view-controller

I have one table called Customer and other called Country. The customer has one country, i'm using belongto association in my Customer model. 
.I have a problem when inserting the country selected from the combo in the database. I load the value in the grid without any problem. I don't know why this is happening !

Below the code:

**Country model:**

```
Ext.define('app.model.Country', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [{name:'name', type:'string'}, 'isActive']
});
```

**Customer model:**

```
Ext.define('app.model.Customer', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [ {
    name : 'name',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'isActive',
    type : 'string'
}],
belongsTo: [
            {
                name: 'country',
                instanceName: 'country',
                model: 'app.model.Country',
                getterName: 'getCountry',
                setterName: 'setCountry',
                associationKey: 'country'
            }
        ]
 });
```

**Country store:**

```
 Ext.define('app.store.Countries', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
model : 'app.model.Country',
autoLoad: true,
pageSize: 35,
autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 35},

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read : 'country/view.action',
            create : 'country/create.action',
            update: 'country/update.action',
            destroy: 'country/delete.action'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: true,
            root: 'data'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Customer store:**

```
 Ext.define('app.store.Customers', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
model : 'app.model.Customer',
autoLoad: true,
pageSize: 35,
autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 35},

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read : 'customer/view.action',
            create : 'customer/create.action',
            update: 'customer/update.action'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: true,
            root: 'data'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }
    }
 });
```

**Country controller**

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Countries', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

views : [ 'country.List', 'country.Edit' ],
stores : [ 'Countries' ],
models : [ 'Country' ],

init : function() {
    this.control({
        'window > countrylist': {
            itemdblclick: this.editCountry
        },
        'countryedit [action=save]' : {
            click : this.save
        },
        'countrylist [action=editcountry]' : {
            click : this.edit
        },
    });
},
editCountry : function(grid,record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('countryedit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
}
    ,
edit : function(button) {
    var view = Ext.widget('countryedit');
},

save : function(button) {
    var win = button.up('window'), form = win.down('form'), record = form
            .getRecord(), values = form.getValues();// var store =
    var isNew = (record == null)                                        //        
    Ext.getStore('Users');
    if (isNew) {            
        record = Ext.create('app.model.Country');
           record.set(values);
            this.getCountriesStore().add(record);
           this.getCountriesStore().sync();
       } else {
            record.set(values);
            this.getCountriesStore().sync();
       }
       win.close();
   },
 });
```

**Customer controller**

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Customers', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
views : [ 'customer.List', 'customer.Edit' ],
stores : [ 'Customers', 'Countries' ],
models : [ 'Customer' ],

init : function() {
    this.control({
        'window > customerlist' : {
            itemdblclick : this.editCustomer
        },
        'customeredit [action=save]' : {
            click : this.save
        },
        'customerlist [action=editcustomer]' : {
            click : this.edit
        },
    });
},
editCustomer : function(grid, record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('customeredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},
edit : function(button) {
    var view = Ext.widget('customeredit');
},

save : function(button) {
    var win = button.up('window'), form = win.down('form'), record = form
            .getRecord(), values = form.getValues();// var store =
    var isNew = (record == null) // Ext.getStore('Users');
    if (isNew) {
        record = Ext.create('app.model.Customer');
        record.set(values);
        this.getCustomersStore().add(record);
        this.getCustomersStore().sync();
    } else {
        record.set(values);
        this.getCustomersStore().sync();
    }
    win.close();
 },
});
```

next, my views...

**Country List**

```
Ext.define('app.view.country.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.countrylist',
store: 'Countries',
columns: [
    {header: "NAME",
     width: 170,
     sortable: true,
     dataIndex: 'name'
    },
    {header: "ISACTIVE",
     width: 160,
     sortable: true,
     dataIndex: 'isActive'
    }
],
viewConfig:{forcefit:true},
title: 'My Countries',
height: 500,
width:535,
frame:true,
tbar: [{
    iconCls: 'icon-user-add',
    text: 'Add Country',
    action: 'editcountry'
}]
});
```

**Country edit:** HERE IS THE FORM !

```
Ext.define('app.view.country.Edit', {
extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.countryedit',

title : 'Add Country',
layout : 'fit',
autoShow : true,
modal:true,

initComponent : function() {
    this.items = [ {
        xtype : 'form',
        items : [ {
            xtype : 'textfield',
            name : 'name',
            fieldLabel : 'Name'
        }, {
            xtype : 'checkbox',
            name : 'isActive',
            fieldLabel : 'IsActive',
            checked : true,
            inputValue : 'Y',
            uncheckedValue : 'N'
        } ]
    } ];

    this.buttons = [ {
        text : 'Save',
        action : 'save'
    }, {
        text : 'Cancel',
        scope : this,
        handler : this.close
    } ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

**Customer list**

```
Ext.define('app.view.customer.List', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias : 'widget.customerlist',
store : 'Customers',
columns : [ {
    header : "NAME",
    width : 170,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'name'
}, {
    header : "ISACTIVE",
    width : 160,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'isActive'
}, {
    header : 'COUNTRY',
    xtype : 'templatecolumn',
    tpl : '{country.name}'
},

],
viewConfig : {
    forcefit : true
},
title : 'My Customers',
height : 500,
width : 535,
frame : true,
tbar : [ {
    iconCls : 'icon-user-add',
    text : 'Add Customer',
    action : 'editcustomer'
} ]
});
```

**Customer edit**

```
Ext.define('app.view.customer.Edit', {
extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.customeredit',
title : 'Edit Customer',
layout : 'fit',
autoShow : true,
modal : true,

initComponent : function() {
    this.items = [ {
        xtype : 'form',
        items : [ {
            xtype : 'textfield',
            name : 'name',
            fieldLabel : 'Name'
        }, {
            xtype : 'checkbox',
            name : 'isActive',
            fieldLabel : 'IsActive',
            checked : true,
            inputValue : 'Y',
            uncheckedValue : 'N'
        }, {
            xtype : 'combo',
            name : 'country_id',
            displayField : 'name',
            fieldLabel : 'Country',
            store : 'Countries',
            valueField : 'id',
            queryMode : 'remote'

        } ]
    } ];

    this.buttons = [ {
        text : 'Save',
        action : 'save'
    }, {
        text : 'Cancel',
        scope : this,
        handler : this.close
    } ];

    this.callParent(arguments);

}
});
```

Comment: please, use https://fiddle.sencha.com, you can create mocking of server side response there too with SimManager

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Do you seriously expect anyone to read all of that code? Narrow down your problem!

Comment: I totally understand why you posted like this.  Sencha best practices is to divide your solution up until individual files.  So, two things:  1) Try making a trivial example and include it all in one html page with javascript tags.  2) I've given up on relationships in sencha and just use extjs5 binding or events to set things.  I've wasted so much time trying to debug relationships I found it just not worth the aggravation.

Comment: You don't know why *what* is happening? You posted a lot of code, but didn't actually describe the problem in any detail.